# Finding sign change of the imaginary part of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to figure out the following problem.

Given is a complex number

$$C=\frac{1}{2}A\,\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\,\varphi}\left(B+D-\sqrt{(B-D)^2+\frac{4}{A\,\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\,\varphi}}}\right)$$

with real coefficients $A>0$, $B>0$, $D>0$ and $0<\varphi<\pi/2$. Now I found numerically that the angle of $C$ is bounded as follows

$$\frac{3}{4}\pi<\mathrm{angle}(C)<\pi \qquad\text{for small enough }A\\
-\pi<\mathrm{angle}(C)<0 \qquad\text{for large enough }A $$

Therefore, depending on the coice of parameter $B$, $D$ and $\varphi$, the angle of $C$ starts somewhere between $3\pi/4$ and $\pi$ and starts rising with rising parameter $A$ until a certain limit. Then a jump occours to somewhere between $-\pi$ and $0$.

Is there a possibility to analytically find a condition for $A$, in dependency of the other parameters, where the jump from a positive angle to a negative angle occurs?

The same question would be: When does the imaginary part of $C$ has a sign change? I do know, there is only one!

Thank you.

Comment: The jump occurs when $\operatorname{Re}(\sqrt{(B-D)^2 + 4A^{-1}e^{i\varphi}}) = B+D$.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Can you explain, how you got this condition?

Comment: Actually, now I think there shouldn't be any jump. Are you sure? Also when you set $B=D$?

Comment: I forgot to add the restriction $D>B$. So the special case of $B=D$ is not possible. If we use the angle-operator, which is defined withhin $-\pi$ and $\pi$, there occurs one jump from $\pi$ to $-\pi$. Of course it would be smooth if we would use the range $0$ to $2 \pi$. But I do need the condition, when $\text{angle}(C)=\pi$.

Comment: The easiest way is to set $\varphi=0$. There $\text{angle}(C)=\pi$ for $A<\frac{1}{B\,D}$ and then jumps to $0$ for $A>\frac{1}{B\,D}$ .

Comment: So, I was not so wrong with my first comment... Now, I see. When the curve passes through the negative x-axis, we get a jump, right? Of course, we also get a jump when we pass through the origin, but this does not happen if $\varphi\neq 0$.

Comment: I am pretty sure the first comment is not correct. I tried the parameters $B=1$, $D=2$ and $\varphi=\frac{\pi}{4}$. The solution for $A$ is approximately $0.14142135623$, which is not fulfilling your condition. Any other ideas?

Comment: No, it is not correct. "Not so wrong" did not mean "right". ;-) Actually, I could give you the equation that one would have to solve for $A$. But it is really ugly and lengthy.

Comment: It seems to me that there is no explicit solution for $A$. I got a view different implicit equations, which I was not able to solve for $A$. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: At least you can get away with the trigonometric terms (except those that involve $\varphi$. Then you have many roots involving $A$. Have you also got that far?